# Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

hi I am trying to create a api gateway from aws console dashboard . and when I have created it is giving this error . I just have dashboard access rn. this is error

```
Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you getting this error in your browser when you create an API Gateway through the console?  This error happens when you try to make an API call that isn't properly signed, which should never happen through the console.

Comment: @TimGustafson created api from web console. now trying to access through POST man.

Comment: @TimGustafson  trying to invoke lambda from postman .

Comment: What happens when you run the Lambda from the console directly?  Where are you seeing the error?